# Is time series regression closer to forecasting or classification?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

I'm working on multivariate time series regression task.

The literature for it seems quite light compared to the problems of Time series classification (using algorithm like rocket for example)  and Time series forecasting (using algorithm like Temporal fusion Transformers or Arima).

I'm not sure how to choose a model inspired by forecasting methods or classification method for a given specific regression problem.
My instinct would be that forecasting methods take more into account issues with dynamic processes like trend/periodicity while classification methods seems to be benchmarked on static data with clear start and end of a time series period like a movement with motion capture, or Electrocardiography data (one heart beat).

So my question would be what to look for in a use case to choose a time series regression method ? and is there literature about this subject ?

Comment: You are confusing concepts, the distinction is between regression and classification, one forecasts real values, the other forecasts categorical values, both are forecasting methods. The choice of which to use depends entirely on what you are forecasting.

Comment: Yes but to do forecasting task where output is a time series people seems to use very different algorithms than for classification of time series. So the question is why this difference ? If it came just from the output format (time series vs no-time-dependant output) I would expect method predicting time-series-output to look like the one of time series classification. But they don't, like no one is using rocket as an encoder for expl. So I was thinking may be the input data may be different (while still being time series) in the different domain

Comment: By "time series regression", do you mean "I have a bunch of time series, and for each series a single target value, and I want a model that can take a new time series and predict the associated target value", where the "target value" is not simply a later observation of the series? If so, what specific kinds of target values do you have in mind? I think some confusion may come from the fact that "time series regression" is often used for time series *forecasting*, which apparently is not what you are looking for.

Comment: For context: I'm trying to propose a set of solutions for time series regression in industrial environment for things like predicting failures of assets, predicting quality at the end of an industrial process, predicting fture value of sensor...
The goal is to propose a starting point for teams that would work on this kind of projects later.

Comment: The crux of the matter for me is that, If I have time series and I want to predict a continuous value from it. It's both close to a classification issue because classification method use feature extraction + a classifier that I can change by a regressor. And it's also close to forecasting because if I can predict a sequence of data points, I can just choose one of them to make a prediction. But at the same time the methods used for classification and forecasting seem quite different

Comment: One insight I found looking into it is that Time Series forecasting method give more weight to recent data compare to Time Series Classification method:
"a regression task of which the aim is to learn the relationship between a time series and a continuous scalar variable; a task closely related to time series classification. This task generalizes time series forecasting, relaxing the requirement that the value predicted be a future value of the input series or primarily depend on more recent values" from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7951134/

Comment: https://www.csse.canterbury.ac.nz/research/reports/HonsReps/2021/hons_2102.pdf here also thay says in section 2.2.2: "This (regression) differs slightly from time series forecasting (TSF) in which the goal is to predict future values in the sequence.[...] TSF usually assumes that the most recent values in the series are more closely related to future values than distant past values. This is a point of difference between TSER and TSF"